# $T_1,T_2,S$ bounded linear operators on a Banach space $X$, with $T_1, T_2$ compact. Show that $T_1+T_2$, $\alpha T_1$, $T_1S$, $ST_1$ are compact.

Tags: functional-analysis

Here is my question:

Let $X$ be a Banach space and suppose $T_1$, $T_2$, $S$ are bounded linear operators from $X$ to $X$, with $T_1$ and $T_2$ compact. Show that $T_1+T_2$, $\alpha T_1$, $ST_1$ and $T_1S$ are all compact ($\alpha$ any scalar). If $F$ is a finite rank operator, show that $SF$ and $FS$ are finite rank as well.

Here is what I have so far:

First, as $T_1,T_2,S$ are bounded linear operators, we know that:

$$\|T_1\|\leq N_1\|x\|, \|T_2\|\leq N_2\|x\|,\|S\|\leq M\|x\|$$

Now here is where I start to get a bit confused... For example, with $T_1+T_2$, I know that this is bounded by $N_1+N_2$. I also know that if $T$ is compact then $T$ is bounded (however I do not believe the opposite is always true). So knowing that $T_1+T_2$ is bounded by $N_1+N_2$, I am not sure how I would show it is compact?

Similar for the rest of them... $\alpha T_1$ is bounded by $\alpha N_1$, $ST_1$ is bounded by $N_1S$, etc.

Help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

Show $T_{1}+T_{2}$ is compact:
 Let $\{ x_{n} \}_{n}$ be a bounded sequence. Then choose $\{ x_{n_{k}}\}_{k}$ such that $\{ T_{1} x_{n_{k}}\}_{k}$ converges. Next choose a subsequence $\{ x_{n_{k_{j}}}\}_{j}$ such that $\{ T_{2} x_{n_{k_{j}}}\}_{j}$ converges. Because every subsequence of a convergent sequence converges, then $\{ T_{1} x_{n_{k_{j}}}\}_{j}$ converges. Therefore $\{ (T_{1}+T_{2})x_{n_{k_{j}}}\}_{j}$ converges. Therefore $T_{1}+T_{2}$ is compact because the image of every bounded sequence contains a convergent subsequence.

Show $T_{1}S$ is compact:
 Let $\{ x_{n} \}_{n}$ be a bounded sequence. Then $\{ y_{n} = Sx_{n} \}_{n}$ is a bounded sequence because $\|y_{n}\| \le \|S\|\|x_{n}\|$ and because $\{ x_{n}\}_{n}$ is bounded. Therefore, there exists a subsequence $\{ y_{n_{k}}= Sx_{n_{k}}\}_{k}$ such that $\{ T_{1}Sx_{n_{k}}\}_{k}$ converges. It follows that $T_{1}S$ is compact.

Show $ST_{1}$ is compact:
 Let $\{ x_{n}\}_{n}$ be a bounded sequence and choose $\{ x_{n_{k}}\}_{k}$ such that $\{ T_{1} x_{n_{k}}\}_{k}$ converges. Because $S$ is continuous, then it maps convergent sequences to converent sequences; hence $\{ ST_{1}x_{n_{k}}\}_{k}$ converges. It follows that $ST_{1}$ is compact.

Show $\alpha T_{1}$ is compact:
 This is a space case of the previous case where $Sx=\alpha x$.

Answer (score 0):

Let $B$ denote the unit ball.
Note that bounded operators are continuous, and an operator is compact iff the image of $B$ is compact, which is true iff the image of $\alpha B$ is compact for any $\alpha > 0$.

Show that a sequence in $(T_1 + T_2)(B)$ has a Cauchy subsequence.

$\alpha T_1(B) = T_1(\alpha B)$, which must be compact.

$S(T_1(B))$ is the image under the continuous map $S$ of the compact set $T_1(S)$ which must be compact.

$T_1(S(B)) \subset T_1(\|S\|\cdot B)$, which is compact.  It suffices to show that $T_1(S(B))$ must also be closed.

The image of a finite dimensional space is finite dimensional, so $SF$ is finite rank.

If $F:Y \to Z$ and $S:X \to Y$, then $F(S(X)) \subset F(Y)$, which is finite dimensional.